# How to change textarea value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got a problem in updating the value within `<textarea>` tags. The procedure is like this, there is an initial value inside textarea, then the user changes it. If I want to use a js script (implemented by a button) to modify the value further, it does not work at all. However, if we do nothing on the textarea, the button works perfectly. So weird to me. Could anyone shed any light on this? The code is posted below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mybutton").click(function() {
    var mystring = "The previous textarea value is <br><em>" + $("#myarea").val() + "</em>";
    $("#myarea").html("Star wars"); // this line doesn't work after editting the textarea but works if you do not edit anything, why?
    $("#placeholder").html(mystring);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>Input whatever you want</div>
  <textarea id="myarea" style="width: 300px; height: 70px">Initial text</textarea>
  <div>
    <button id="mybutton">Click after editing</button>
    <br> The button is supposed to change the text to <em>Star wars</em>.
  </div>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `val()` not `html()` to set **value** of form controls

Comment: You are right, `val()` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    var mystring = "The previous textarea value is <br><em>" + $("#myarea").val() + "</em>";
    $("#myarea").val("Star wars"); //The changes have to be made on this line
    $("#placeholder").html(mystring);
  });
});
```

Inorder to change the value of textarea ***use val() , instead of html()***.